# Can I use pagefile or swap area for massive data structure in python?

Tags: python, memory, structure

I have question about use massive data structure
(list, dict, tuple, etc.)

If my computer have memory size 2GB, Can I use 3GB or more data structure in memory?

This question occured when use massive matrix data.

For solve this question,
I think use pagefile or swap area during processing.

but I can not know 'how', and I want find more other methods.

I waiting for reply.
Thank you for read this question article.

Comment: The OS (Windows at least) is automatically going to use OS when it runs out of RAM. You don't have to do anything. The question is do you want that to happen. Once OS starts swapping, everything slows down about millionfold and the computer becomes irresponsive. You should probably be asking how to avoid the swap ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @zvone :). frankly, I want find operating methods for massive data using list data structure without extend swap area . but I was not found properly alternative to list data structure without in memory. So It is agonize me.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with GBs of data in memory? There are other ways to process data, but what exactly that depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses all the resources provided by your OS (which can be quite problematic for other services). If you want to use a swap file in order to increase the memory for your application, you have to do this on the OS layer and not in your software. There are some ways to get hold of this sort of problem:

- Write your code more efficient, for example using [sparse-matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) or tile your matrix in pieces, using only the pieces necessary for the moment
- Enable additional hardware resources, such as swap or RAM.
- Compress the information with suitable algorithms

To give a more precise answer, you have to provide more detailed information about your problem.